# Create an IAM user to give access to perform certain tasks in AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I need to create IAM user so that user can perform below tasks

```
Log Management & Audits
Intrusion Detection
Managed Backup
Centralized Anti-virus
Vulnerability Scanning
Monitoring
Hardened AMI (Amazon Machine Images)
```

I would like to know how this can be done in AWS management console. I am new to AWS

Comment: Please edit your question to provide details of _how_ you intend to do the above. For example, what do you mean by "Intrusion Detection"? How will this be implemented? What permissions are required? Is this just a list of activities you obtained from a document somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

IAM users are users of the Amazon API/CLI/UI, not OS users. You can create an IAM user that can create EC2 instances, and on those instances there will be a default OS user that you can log in with using an SSH key you can provide. For Amazon Linux images the user will be called 'ec2-user', for other distributions it will be e.g. 'ubuntu' or 'centos', and they will have sudo privileges.

For all of the things you ask you need to be able to login on the instance itself via SSH. So you need to either share the default user's SSH key with that person, or you need to create a second user on the machine itself.